# I was referring to Angular material for customising Typography, getting the error that SassError: Undefined variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, node-sass, typography

here is my error

```
ERROR in ./src/secondary.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-4!./src/secondary.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
    ╷
120 │ @include mat-base-typography($custom-typography);
    │                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You have to import the file containing the variable (and only variables !) at the beginning of your scss file.